# Running programs over ssh

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I am planning to log in to my college PC using ssh and run some simulations. These simulations take very long time, so I would like the relevant process to run longer than the ssh session (I want to log in, run the process, log out and collect the results the next day).

How can I do it

1. If the process is a command line tool that doesn't expect any inputs (so that I just need the resulting output file)?
2. If the process is a GUI, which sadly doesn't save the results to a file, but displays it instead. So in this case I was thinking of using `ssh -X ...` command, but then I don't know how to reconnect to the open window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your college's computer runs all the time:

1. Use [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sf.net) and live happily ever after.
2. Apparently, [`xpra`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra) offers that, i.e. it attempts to be "Screen for X11".  (I've never used it, though.)

(There're other solutions for (1.), e.g. [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and IO redirection, but Screen probably is the canonical tool for these kinds of issues. (You can then just re-attach to the detached session and see if the simulation still runs etc...))

Comment: An alternative to 'screen' is 'nohup'. It has only very basic functionality compared to screen but it is more general available.

Comment: @antje-m: you're right and I've just edited the answer some minutes ago `:)`