# How to display an X11 screen from a remote machine? (Alternative to ssh -X)

Tags: x11, ssh-tunneling, framebuffer, xvfb

I am locally on a machine without root rights. X forwarding is disabled.

Remotely I am running a process on a machine without a screen, using the `Xvfb` virtual framebuffer which simulates an X server but discards any image displayed.  This works reasonably well.

Now, some things are not working, and I need to debug by looking at the X screen.  I did take a screenshot in `Xvfb` with `xwd -display :99 -root -out /tmp/screenshot.xwdump` but it is quite complicated to look at many of them in a sequence.

**Is there a way to connect with from my client to the server, and then connect to the framebuffer in order to display the remote X window locally?**

This could be a second `ssh` channel.  The X program should ideally keep on running after disconnecting and I would like to be able to start it before the second connection if possible (think `spice`).

I only have outgoing connections to the server, and only to port 22.  On neither machine root rights are available.

PS: This question is similar to [Running programs over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/running-programs-over-ssh) but my requirement is that no program can be installed as `root` on client or server which seems to rule out `xpra` (the answer given there) unless I find an easy way to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running programs over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/running-programs-over-ssh)

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, in a way, yes, as @mviereck's answer points out. I am, however, hoping for an *easier solution* as `xpra` seems very difficult to install as non-root from src (which needs libraries that are not installed).

Comment: ffmpeg can create a video from your desktop: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding the problem. Is your local machine an X server? Do you know about setting `DISPLAY` or using `--display`? If so, what happens when you do so?

Comment: There are alternatives to Xpra like VNC/RDP with an X server, but they also require compiling/installation of a non-trivial amount of stuff. As you need to compile/install something X server related, I don't think there's a way to avoid this. Alternative: Make the X **clients** on your remote machine not connect to Xvfb, but set `DISPLAY` so they connect to some X server on your local machine (which you can simply install with root rights).

Comment: @G-Man I have two machine, both Linux. Local one with GUI Wayland log-in, remote without monitor. I know about DISPLAY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xpra` is your friend: http://xpra.org/. Install `xpra` on server and client.

Start `xpra` server over ssh with

```
xpra start-desktop ssh:user@server:XVFBDISPLAY --use-display --start-via-proxy=no
```

Alternatively: If you are already logged in to the server, you can start xpra server with

```
xpra start-desktop :XVFBDISPLAY --use-display --start-via-proxy=no
```

Start `xpra` on client with

```
xpra attach ssh:server:XVFBDISPLAY
```

You can detach and reattach later again:

```
xpra detach ssh:server:XVFBDISPLAY
```

(Replace `XVFBDISPLAY` with the display number of `Xvfb`.)

Comment: Thanks, that could be it. However, I was hoping to have something easier to install without root rights. Looks like it even needs libraries which is always a pain in user space.

Comment: You are talking about `Xvfb`'s screen. Does that mean I run both `Xfvb` and `xpra`?

Comment: @Ned64 Yes, xpra attaches to the already running Xvfb display. Without option `--use-display` it would set up `Xvfb` (or `Xdummy`) on itself.

Comment: @Ned64 Maybe it is possible to compile `xpra` with statically linked libraries? Though, it may become a colossal binary. You can ask for this at xpra.org, the developer is quite helful.

Comment: Thanks. I will vote your answer up because it very likely solves the problem technically even if I cannot test it very soon due to the complexity involved.

Comment: @Ned64 `x11vnc` is also able to show an already running display if you happen to have it on your server. If `docker` is available for you, there are further possibilities.